# how do I print a binary double array from commandline (unix)

Tags: c++, c, bash, binary, octal

I got binary file, that contains doubles. How do i print that out to a terminal.
I've tried octaldump 'od' but cant figure out the syntax I've tried something like

```
head -c80 |od -f
```

But that doesnt work, the man page for od is extremely bad.

I've made a c program that does what I want, 
something like assuming 10double chunks.

```
double tmp[10];
while(fread(tmp,sizeof(double),10,stdin))
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)  printf("%f\t",tmp[i]);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) utility?

```
hexdump -e ' [iterations]/[byte_count] "[format string]" ' filename
```

Where format string should be `"%f"`, byte count should be 8, and iterations the amount of floats you want to read

Answer (score 4):

The `od` command you're looking for is

```
od -t fD
```

(That means "floating point values, of `double` size").